# Functionality of the BPF hash of maps structure

Tags: hashmap, trace, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I'm writing a BPF tool that maintains a per-process trace, which means I'll need a 2d data structure of some sort. To bypass the 512 byte limitation, I've decided that going with the supported structs (maps) is my best bet. After glancing at the [iovisor docs](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/reference_guide.md#14-bpf_hash_of_maps), it seemed like `BPF_HASH_OF_MAPS` was the structure I needed. I presumed this structure offered a key-value pairing wherein the "value" was another BPF map. However, based on the parameters it takes, the "outer" structure seems to be an array (personally, from the github documenation, I can't tell the difference between `BPF_HASH_OF_MAPS` and `BPF_ARRAY_OF_MAPS`). Have I been misled: does the `BPF_HASH_OF_MAPS` structure provide hashmap like functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. **bcc doesn't make a different between `BPF_HASH_OF_MAPS` and `BPF_ARRAY_OF_MAPS`, as least in how they're exposed**. In the kernel, they actually are two different data structures and a BPF hash of maps can have keys of various sizes.

[bcc defines](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/2fa54c0bd388898fdda58f30dcfe5a68d6715efc/src/cc/export/helpers.h#L294-L295) a hardcoded `int` as the key type (first `int` below) for the `BPF_HASH_OF_MAPS` maps:

```
#define BPF_HASH_OF_MAPS(_name, _inner_map_name, _max_entries) \
  BPF_TABLE("hash_of_maps$" _inner_map_name, int, int, _name, _max_entries)
```

To use different key types, you can simply use `BPF_TABLE` in place of `BPF_HASH_OF_MAPS`.